# How to parse delimited TStringlist to dynamic multidimensional array of integer?

Tags: arrays, delphi, parsing, delphi-xe7, tstringlist

I have been searching high and low for a Delphi function or any info that can parse a space delimited TStringList(Loaded from *.asc file) to a dynamic 2D array of integer.

What I have is an ASCII grid file with elevations in a grid format. Firstly I read the file into a TStringlist, where I extract the header data to variables, then delete the header data from the TStringlist. What I'm left with is a TStringlist with only elevation data in a grid of 3601 x 3601, with each value separated by a space. With this Stringlist still in memory, I'd like to fill a 2D array of integer with the elevation data, then free the TStringList.

From my searches I stumbled upon a piece of code [here](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,14394.15.html) that kind of worked, but not completely.

What I have is:

```
var sourceData, tmpGrid, tmpRow : TStringList;
    val : String;
    Pos, i, j, k, l : Integer;
    nCols, nRows, noData : Integer;
    xllCorner, yllCorner, cellSize : Extended;
    Dem : array of array of Integer;
begin
 val := '';
 sourceData := TStringList.Create;
 tmpGrid := TStringList.Create;
 tmpRow := TStringList.Create;
 tmpRow.StrictDelimiter := True;
 tmpRow.Delimiter := ' ';
 sourceData.LoadFromFile('D:\ZA_DEM_DATA\Bulk_Order_466486\ARCASCII\s30_e026_1arc_v3.asc');

nCols := StrToInt(StripNonConforming(sourceData.Strings[0], ['0'..'9', '+', '-', '.']));
nRows := StrToInt(StripNonConforming(sourceData.Strings[1], ['0'..'9', '+', '-', '.']));
xllCorner := StrToFloat(StripNonConforming(sourceData.Strings[2], ['0'..'9', '+', '-', '.']));
yllCorner := StrToFloat(StripNonConforming(sourceData.Strings[3], ['0'..'9', '+', '-', '.']));
cellSize := StrToFloat(StripNonConforming(sourceData.Strings[4], ['0'..'9', '+', '-', '.']));
noData := StrToInt(StripNonConforming(sourceData.Strings[5], ['0'..'9', '+', '-', '.']));

Edit1.Text := IntToStr(nCols);
Edit2.Text := IntToStr(nRows);
Edit3.Text := FloatToStr(xllCorner);
Edit4.Text := FloatToStr(yllCorner);
Edit5.Text := FloatToStr(cellSize);
Edit6.Text := IntToStr(noData);

for I := 0 to 5 do
 begin
  sourceData.Delete(0);
 end;
//This is where I start parsing my TStrinList
tmpGrid.DelimitedText := sourceData.Text;
SetLength(Dem, nCols, nRows);

Edit7.Text := IntToStr(sourceData.Count);

try
 for i := 0 to sourceData.Count -1 do
   for j := 0 to sourceData.Count -1 do
    begin
     Dem[i][j] := StrToInt(tmpGrid.Strings[i]);
    end;
finally
 sourceData.Free;
end;

StringGrid1.ColCount := nCols;
StringGrid1.RowCount := nRows;
//This is mainly to visualise the data while testing the code
for i := 0 to nCols -1 do
  for j := 0 to nRows -1 do
   begin
    StringGrid1.Cells[i, j] := IntToStr(dem[i, j]);
   end;
 end;
```

The result I get is the first "row" of data as displayed in the original file, but copied to all rows of the array. For example:

Original Data:

```
1. 1245 1268 1232 1258
2. 1354 1321 1578 1689
3. 1461 1423 1475 1427
4. 1598 1541 1562 1550
```

What I get is:

```
1. 1245 1268 1232 1258
2. 1245 1268 1232 1258
3. 1245 1268 1232 1258
4. 1245 1268 1232 1258
```

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, looks like `[debug-this-code-for-me]` should be a major tag here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the cause of the wrong results

```
 for i := 0 to sourceData.Count -1 do
   for j := 0 to sourceData.Count -1 do
    begin
     Dem[i][j] := StrToInt(tmpGrid.Strings[i]);
    end;
```

You have moved the actual data from SourceData to tmpGrid, which is not needed. Instead, assign one line at a time from SourceData to tmpRow, then read the values one at a time from tmpRow, and assign to the value array:

```
for i := 0 to SourceData.Count-1 do
begin
  tmpRow.DelimitedText := SourceData[i];
  for j := 0 to tmpRow.Count-1 do
    Dem[i,j] := StrToInt(tmpRow[j]);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just after this code line

```
//This is where I start parsing my TStrinList
tmpGrid.DelimitedText := sourceData.Text;
```

your `sourceData` contains 4 lines of text

```
1245 1268 1232 1258
1354 1321 1578 1689
1461 1423 1475 1427
1598 1541 1562 1550
```

and `tmpGrid` contains 16 lines of text

```
1245
1268
1232
1258
1354
1321
1578
1689
1461
1423
1475
1427
1598
1541
1562
1550
```

But you only access the tmpGrid lines from 0 to 3 for each row

```
 for i := 0 to sourceData.Count -1 do
   for j := 0 to sourceData.Count -1 do
    begin
     Dem[i][j] := StrToInt(tmpGrid.Strings[i]);
    end;
```

You should change your code to use the values from `nCols` and `nRows` and then calculate the line inside `tmpGrid`

```
 for i := 0 to nCols -1 do
   for j := 0 to nRows -1 do
    begin
     Dem[i][j] := StrToInt(tmpGrid.Strings[i + j*nCols]);
    end;
```

```
i = 0 // first column
j = 1 // second row
i + j * nCols => 0 + 4 => fifth line of tmpGrid (zero indexed)
```

Comment: Thanks Sir Rufo, your answer helped. At first I thought something caused an endless loop, since my application froze and stayed that way for over 10min. I decided to test again with a smaller block of data, 1/4 of the size to be exact, and it seem to have worked. I do however have a problem with the speed...it took 1min 09sec to complete the task with the test data which is 900x900. Is there any faster method I could try to explore, or should I rather approach the task differently?

Comment: @Martin Did you include writing to the StringGrid in your speed test? I found your timing report so unbelievable that I did a test (without the StringGrid) and reading a 900 x 900 value text file, converting values to integer and assigning to the array takes about a second. I used the method I suggested in my answer, without the tmpGrid StringList.

Comment: @ Tom, thanks for your comment, it got me on the right track. Apparrently the following line "Memo1.Lines.Assign(tmpGrid);" was the culprit. Also, just a side note, I had an issue with your answer at first as it returned with " '' is not a valid integer" error, but managed to fix it with Trim. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Martin When you address comments with @, don't leave a space after, because then the notification of the adressee will not work. The issue with `not valid integer` was probably because of a space at the end of each line in SourceData, which creates an empty line in tmpRow. Good you found a fix.

Comment: @Tom, sorry about that, this is my first post here, so still learning the ropes. Yes, when assigning the data in it's delimited form to Memo, I noticed a leading and trailing space, but thought `DelimitedText` would sort it out. So I used your solution with the `Trim` function and it seems to be working great. I now have to create a bitmap from the values in the array to visualize the data as a Heightmap, once this is done i will be able to compare it with the original Heightmap and verify the results. Thanks for all the help. One last thing, how do I accept your answer?

Comment: @Tom, disregard my last question, found the tick :)